# Prove that for a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{K} [x]$ there is a unique polynomial $g$ of degree $\le 1$ such that $x^2+1|f-g$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

I am assuming $\deg(0) = -\infty$ so that this holds

At first I thought that the polynomial dividing $f-g$ was $x^2-1$, so I took a geometrical approach and showed that such a polynomial $g$ is a straight line on the plane that passes through the points $(1,f(1))$ and $(-1,f(-1))$.

However, the roots of $x^2+1 $ are complex, so I have no idea how to go about this

I thought of maybe using a Lagrange Polynomial in the same way, but I'm not sure if I can use it in the Complex plane (I know the Lagrange polynomial will always yield a unique polynomial of the lowest degree passing through certain points).

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Do you know about Euclidean division for polynomials?

Comment: Yes. But how would I use it here?

Comment: Performing Euclidean division on $f$ by $X^{2}+1$, there is a unique $g(X) \in K[X]$ with $\deg(g(X)) < \deg(X^{2}+1) = 2$ such that $f(X) = (X^{2}+1)q(X) + g(X)$ for some $q(X) \in K[X]$. Then $f(X) - g(X) = q(X)(X^{2}+1)$, so $X^{2}+1$ divides $f-g$.

Comment: ohhhh ok, that's the interpretation I was missing. Thanks!